# Mule not honouring log4j2.component.properties or log4j2.system.properties

Tags: log4j, mule, log4j2, mulesoft, mule4

I've a mule application which needs to load log4j2.xml from different locations as per the environment shown below.

**app1**

```
dev --> /etc/dev/app1/log4j2.xml    
sit --> /etc/sit/app1/log4j2.xml    
.    .    .    
prod --> /etc/prod/app1/log4j2.xml
```

I don't want to use spring bean loading as by the time this bean is loaded, Mule would have already initiated log context for this app1 with default configuration and writes few logs to it.

Within log4j functionality, there are **log4j2.system.properties** and **log4j2.component.properties** files. When either of them is added to classpath (src/main/resources) with **log4j.configurationFile**  property in it, it is supposed to pick up this file during **application startup** itself.

Reference: [Log4j System Properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties)

```
log4j.configurationFile=${config.path}/app1/log4j2.xml
```

**config.path** is defined in wrapper as system property and available to app1 holding the env path ("/etc/dev" if dev or "/etc/sit" if sit etc..)

However, both of these files are not picking up by Mule and resolving to default configuration.

Can someone please assist in making any of these files pick up by Mule during application startup itself?

Comment: "loading log4j2.xml from its own path for each environment" what is an environment in this contenxt? A Mule server, an application? 
Also please focus your post in one question or issue. Making several questions together could make the question to be closed as lacking focus.

Comment: Completely reworded it. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: It seems likely that if this mechanism works at all with Mule 4 then it should work at the server level rather than the Mule application level. Have you tried to add the files to the boot classpath?

Comment: I haven’t tried that approach but it doesn’t fit my use-case even if it works at server level :(

Comment: I have tried a similar thing some time ago, and observed the same thing. Mule runtime totally ignores most of the log4j related configuration properties.

Comment: May I ask how much different are the `log4j.xml`. If they only have different `Appenders` or `Loggers` then I think there is a way to make it work.

Comment: They are the same. You would ask why can’t I load from classpath if all are same. Reason being, when updating the log4j levels, I need to restart the app (here app is mule domain) to reflect the changes which causes outage. So I’m trying to leverage “monitoringInterval” field within log4j2.xml keeping it outside of danger zone i.e classpath. 

Would like to hear your way - will it load log4j2.xml during application start up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research, we have to update mule_artifact.json with "logConfig" key to define the location of external log4j2.xml file in server relative to mule_home path.

The same path may not work in local but you can create "mklink" to resemble server path in local.

I've tested successfully both.